# How to remove an apt repository which seems to be showing up after sudo apt update in the terminal but not present in /etc/apt/sources.list.d?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository, elementary-os

I accidentally added a repository with `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"` and since then I am getting an error whenever I try the `sudo apt update` command. I am pretty sure its because of the above repository. I searched on google and found out that the repository can be removed by manually visiting the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ folder but the above repository is not present there. I have also tried the `ppa-purge` but was unable to remove the repository. How do I remove the above repository?

[image: screenshot of "sudo apt update"]

[image: screenshot of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.   and don't post GUI directory listings, either - post the text output of `ls -l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) you can use the same command with the `-r` option to remove the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

I didn't fully understand in which case a new repository file is added to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, but if it's not there, then it must have been added to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and you can also remove it manually from there.

Answer (score 3):

The [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) (`man add-apt-repository`) says that it manages repositories not only under the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` but also in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

If you can't find a reference to your unwanted repository under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` you should also check the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

As mentioned [already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541905/100397) the documentation also describes the `-r` (`--remove-`) flag to remove an existing repository.